# SharePoint intranet portal to notification on Microsoft teams using a Microsoft graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams

To notify, I try to achieve Microsoft Teams Activity Notification SharePoint online intranet portal updates.

I am trying to achieve and looking for a SharePoint online site to create an event, list, and update saved in the list to notify in the Microsoft Teams activity icon.

How can we implement those features and try the possibilities?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.